# django template table trouble OR

Tags: django, templates, python-3.x

So I have this dictionary:

> [{'name': 'Strom', 'jahr': 2014, 'summe': 1258.0}, {'name': 'Strom', 'jahr': 2013, 'summe': 0}, {'name': 'Strom', 'jahr': 2012, 'summe': 0}, {'name': 'Erdgas', 'jahr': 2014, 'summe': 1425.7485714285715}, {'name': 'Erdgas', 'jahr': 2013, 'summe': 0}, {'name': 'Erdgas', 'jahr': 2012, 'summe': 0}]

And I want to get it into a table:

```
Energy        2014      2013     2012

Strom         1258         0        0

Erdgas        1425.74      0        0
```

There will always be 3 Years to display, but thare could be more than 2 rows.

Iam not that good at CSS and HTML so its mostly try and error, and this is my html file so far:

```
   {% extends 'base.html' %}
   {% load verbrauchererfassung_tags %}
   {% block content %}
   {{Verbrauch}}
    <h1 class="page-header">Verbraucheranzeige</h1>
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Energieträger</th>
          {% for y in Years %}
          <th>{{ y }}</th>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for v in Verbrauch %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}
     <tr>
    <td>{{v.name}}</td>

    {% endif %}

    {% for verbrauch in Verbrauch %}
    <td>{{verbrauch.summe}} </td>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 or forloop.last%}</tr>{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

    {% endblock %}
```

Which looks like this :

```
Energieträger   2014    2013    2012
Strom           1258,0     0       0
1425,7485714285715  0    0
1258,0  0   0
1425,7485714285715  0   0
1258,0  0   0
1425,7485714285715  0   0
Erdgas          1258,0  0   0
1425,7485714285715  0   0
1258,0  0   0
1425,7485714285715  0   0
1258,0  0   0
1425,7485714285715  0   0
```

Yeah it drives me crazy, I think I might be on a wrong aproache here, can you guys help me out?

**EDIT:**

So after a long break I decided to order my dictionary like this:

```
[{'name': 'Strom', 2: 2013.0, 3: 2012.0, 1: 1258.0}, {'name': 'Erdgas', 2: 0, 3: 0, 1: 1425.7485714285715}]
```

Which resulted in a template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load verbrauchererfassung_tags %}
{% block content %}
{{Verbrauch}}
    <h1 class="page-header">Verbraucheranzeige</h1>
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Energieträger</th>
          {% for y in Years %}
          <th>{{ y }}</th>
          {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      </thead>
    <tbody>

    {% for v in Verbrauch %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}
     <tr>
    {% endif %}
    <td>{{v.name}}</td>
    <td>{{v.1}}</td>
    <td>{{v.2}}</td>
    <td>{{v.3}}</td>
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"3" or forloop.last%}</tr>{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}


    </table>

{% endblock %}
```

And this nice Table (I made values according to the years, so I can see if I got the order right)

```
Energietraeger  2014    2013    2012
Strom           1258,0  2013,0  2012,0
Erdgas         1425,74     0    0
```

Comment: here: `{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}<tr>` - move the `endif` __before__ the `td`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have problems with that since your code:

```
 {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}
     <tr>
 {% endif %}
    <td>{{v.name}}</td>
    <td>{{v.1}}</td>
    <td>{{v.2}}</td>
    <td>{{v.3}}</td>
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"3" or forloop.last%}</tr>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

will add a tr every 3 loops and after the last loop which is not what you want anymore. So I think your html will look like:

```
    <tr>
    <td>Strom</td>
    <td> 1258,0</td>
    <td> 2013,0</td>
    <td> 2012,0</td>
    </tr>
    <td>Erdgas</td>
    <td> 1425,74</td>
    <td> 0</td>
    <td> 0</td>
    </tr>
```

So for two it might be displayed correctly but as you can see before `Erdgas` there is a `<tr>` missing.

The correct Solution will be:

```
{% for v in Verbrauch %}

<tr>
<td>{{v.name}}</td>
<td>{{v.1}}</td>
<td>{{v.2}}</td>
<td>{{v.3}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Your loop iterates over the list elements which have the right number of fields (name, 1, 2, 3) So you dont need to do some division tests. And you have to add new table rows for each element in the loop.

In your example the forloop will run from 0 to 1 because you have to elements in the list

1st Element: {'name': 'Strom', 2: 2013.0, 3: 2012.0, 1: 1258.0}

2nd Element: {'name': 'Erdgas', 2: 0, 3: 0, 1: 1425.7485714285715}